# Интересная регулярка

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Стоит задача убрать первые цифры из строки "63ete4tet4". 
Делал так

```
var str = "63ete4tet4";
var result = Regex.Replace(str, "\\d+", "");
```

Но было предложена еще одна регулярка - `[^0-9+][\w\W]*` Странно, но она работает. Из нескольких онлайн сервисов проверки она заработало только в одном. И в C# коде тоже заработала. Вопрос - Что делает это регулярка? Почему и как  она работает?

Comment: Как же она у Вас работает? Вторая регулярка не может работать так, как Вы описали. Вам нужно `^\d+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша первая регулярка работает, но только потому, что один раз заменяет. Если входная строка будет такая "abc123def", то замена будет "странной".

Вторая предложенная регулярка делает следующее: первый символ - любой символ кроме цифр и символа +, а дальше - любой символ (любой аски символ) в любых количествах. Любой - потому что \w и \W - взаимоисключающие.

Как эта регулярка работала - очень просто - она искала первый не цифровой символ (плюс "плюс") и брала все последующие символы. Но вот только применять ее нужно для матчинга, а на замены.

Но автору подобной регулярки нужно рассказть, что лучше уже ее написать так `[\d+].*`.

***upd***
в java всегда нужно помнить о том, что слеши в регулярках нужно правильно экранировать. А то результаты могут быть неожиданными и странными.

Comment: Похоже, они по-разному работают с переводами строк: http://ideone.com/55IRIh

Answer (score 1):

`[^0-9+]` - один или более любых символов кроме цифр,
`[\w\W]*` - ноль или более любых буквенных и цифровых символов

т.е. `[^0-9+]` - это первая буква после цифр, `[\w\W]*` - все последующие символы

Comment: В чём смысл `[\w\W]`, почему не `.`? Не первый раз уже такое вижу

Comment: в выражении [^0-9+] плюс это просто плюс.

Comment: @ixSci Насколько понимаю, `[\w\W]` совпадет с любым символом вне зависимости от флагов регулярки, в то время как у точки проблемы с переводами строк. В яваскрипте, насколько помню, другим способом перевод строки и не словить.